# 150 years ago today in PHP

Tags: php, function, date

I am looking to have a one line return function to get the date 150 years ago from today.

I currently have,

```
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-150 year'));
```

The problem is this returns 1970-01-01 instead of 150 years ago.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a unix timestamp (seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`), so the earliest date it can understand is `1970-01-01`. Since 150 years ago today is before `1970-01-01` `strtotime` is returning `false`, which is interpreted as a 0 timestamp by date, resulting in an output of `1970-01-01`. To work around this limitation use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime('-150 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output (as of `2020-02-19`):

```
1870-02-19
```

If the code does need to be in one line, you can write:

```
$date = (new DateTime('-150 year'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VgAWR)